# javascript counter Tower of Honoi

Tags: javascript, recursion, counter

im trying to implement the Tower of Hanoi (Recursion) but dont know how to do it writing recursive counter. I have this so far

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Joxongir/cvx2fx7x/)

```js
var nomer = 0;

document.getElementById("sub").onclick = function() {
  nomer = 0;
  nomer = document.getElementById("number").value;
  Reshenie(nomer);
}

function Reshenie(nomer) {
  return document.getElementById("Result").innerHTML = "Your input was: " + nomer.bold() + " disks;" + "<br><br> it will take total of " + (Math.pow(2, nomer) - 1) + " moves";
}
```

```html
<b>Enter a number.</b>
<br>
<br>
<input type="number" class="number" id="number">
<input type="button" class="myButton" value="Submit" id="sub">
<br>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

I did it using (Math.pow(2, nomer) - 1) but that is not correct way of do it. Any pointers how to do it writing recursive counter?

Thank you

Comment: There are quite a few implementations on github. Have you looked at them? https://github.com/search?l=JavaScript&q=Tower+of+hanoi&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "writing recursive counter".  Do you mean that you want to compute 2^n-1 using a recursive process?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute 2^n-1 recursively.  Let this value be f(n).

```
if n < 1, f(n) => undefined
if n = 1, f(n) => 1
else
  f(n) => 2*f(n-1) + 1
```

Let's check the math for
f(n) in terms of f(n-1) ...

```
f(n) = 2^n - 1
     = 2 * 2^(n-1) - 1 
     = 2 * 2^(n-1) - 2 + 1 
     = 2 * (2^(n-1) - 1) + 1
     = 2 * f(n-1) + 1
```

Does that move you toward a solution?